# Javascript: Remove letters outside of two parentesis

Tags: javascript

So, hello. I edited the entire thing.

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    let results = await db.collection("malwarepad-website").find("6047667ff156cb8135bdaa88").toArray()
    //var resultsConverted = results.toString();
    //let resultsFinal = resultsConverted.split('"');
    console.log(results)
    res.render('index.ejs', { startText: results });
})
```

In the above code I want to only keep the second part of it specified better in this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wi031.png

I want to create a variable containing the following:

```
Hello, and welcome to my website. I don't know how you found me but yo...
```

I already have a constant containing the search results, but it is this:

```
[
  {
    _id: 6047667ff156cb8135bdaa88,
    mainPage: "Hello, and welcome to my website. I don't know how you found me but you're welcome :)."
  }
]
```

**Thanks for the understanding :)**

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post details of what you've tried and what problem you're encountering.

Comment: One way is to split on double quote and take the second element from the resulting array.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz I'm saying that I'll make a new const with Important Part inside

Comment: The obvious answer would be to extract the important part using regular expressions, but we don't really know what scenarios are you working with in reality. In this case a simple regexp would be enough.

Comment: @Dropout I'll try that later

Answer (score 2):

```
a = a.split("\"")[1]
```

Comment: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: results.split is not a function

Comment: can you share what you are trying to run? @FightGamingX

Comment: just node index.js

Comment: can you share a code sample?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean extracting what's inside `double quotation`s, you have two methods:

1 - Use Regular Expressions:

You can use regular expression `/.*"(.*)".*/` which tries to capture everything inside parentheses. You can use `exec` method. like :

`const importantPart = /.*"(.*)".*/.exec(a)[1]` (`a` is your variable)

2 - Using `indexOf` string methods

In JavaScript strings have two useful methods: `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf`. In addition to a `substring`.

You can use these to extract the important part:

`a.substring(a.indexOf('"') + 1, a.lastIndexOf('"'))`

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions. One could be:

```js
const a = 'odshniudfskdjnfdsjnf"Important part"fererferferef';
let a_splitted = a.split('"');
console.log(a_splitted[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to extract the part that you need.

```
const a = 'odshniudfskdjnfdsjnf"Important part"fererferferef';
let result = a.match(/\"(.*)\"/);
console.log(result[1]);
```

There are a lot of what-ifs though.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const a = 'odshniudfskdjnfdsjnf"Important part"fererferferef';

let regex = /(?<=\")(.*?)(?=\")/;

let result = regex.exec(a)[0];

console.log(result);
```